# Contacting an API, Error's just some of the time...?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, api, error-handling

I have written PHP code which connects to MYSQL to look up information, sends it to an API, and get a response to write back into a new table.

Sometimes it works perfectly, other times it doesn't. When it doesn't it gives me this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , '', '', '')' at line 1
```

or sometimes it will write one or two entries into the new table and then give me the error at a different line. Oh, and even if I choose the same data for the API to look up and send, sometimes it will work and sometimes it won't.( I have taken all commas out of the strings that are being sent to cut back on possible errors with commas.)

I'm wondering if this is a problem with the API or my code. I can't understand how it would work for some of the time, and be a problem on the code problem, which leads to my thoughts on possible API problems.

My hypotheses are:

1. The API key I have has limited functionality and so limits my results.
2. It takes to long for a response and so times out my request.

Do either of these make sense? Any other ideas?

Here's the php code that sometimes gets back something:

Sometimes it will echo out. But othertimes it won't. The function $request->whatever are available in the API functions php.

I believe the sql line that is throwing the error has to do with this:

```
insertRow($db, $new_table, $Merchant, $ips, $scoreBeforeGeo, $geoFactor, $scoreAfterGeo, $category, $overall_protocol, $protocol_name);

function insertRow($db, $new_table, $Merchant, $ips, $scoreBefore, $geoFactor,      $scoreAfter, $category, $overall, $protocol)
{
   $insert = "INSERT INTO $new_table " . " VALUES('$Merchant', '$ips', $scoreBefore, $geoFactor, $scoreAfter, '$category', '$overall', '$protocol');";
$q = mysqli_query($db, $insert) || die(mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Again, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't....

Comment: To check for definite what is the problem, when you receive an error in your query you could log what the actual query was and also some other information that may help you find the cause of this, such as the page contents of the API, etc.

Comment: Is this error coming from the API? Which code is talking to MySQL, the API you are using or your code?

Comment: the error seems to come from MYSQL, and I've tried simply echoing out the variables from the API before it writes to MYSQL so that I can see what they are. Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't. Thats another reason why I think it has to do with the API. But even if the variables aren't return, shouldn't MYSQL still be able to write the table just leaving those columns blank?

Comment: @user1475765 - I understand the error is from MySQL, who is writing to the database, the API or your code? Can you post a sample of the code that generates this error? You mention that it 'somtimes works', do you mean that passing the same data repeatedly will sometimes work and sometimes generate this error? That sounds quite strange to me, generally malformed SQL does not intermittently work.

Comment: I've added some of the code. I am writing to the database. The API simply evaluates what I send it, and then I write it for storage. And yes I mean the same data will sometimes produce results, othertimes throw the error, sometimes throw the error at a different line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not sanitize the input to the query or pass it via parameters.  This means that if the data being passed into the INSERT statement has characters (such as apostrophes) that will be interpreted as SQL syntax, it will mess up your statement.  **It also has the potential to destroy or provide unintended access to your data.**  In other words, it is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Use prepared statements to guard against this.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I was just starting to write up using the sql prepare. I will just upvote you instead.

Comment: I understand the sql injection portion. Its internal so I'm not too worried about this. But what I still don't get is why sometimes it works with the same data and other times it doesn't. Do you have any theories on that?

Comment: The error you're getting strongly indicates that there are characters in your data that interfere with the SQL syntax -- most likely a non-escaped apostrophe.  Try converting it to the prepared statement approach and see if you still get errors.

Comment: does binding the parameters and implementing it through prepare take care of apostrophe's and commas with sql syntax?

Comment: Yes, they will be passed as literal data rather than being interpreted as SQL syntax.

Comment: Just want you to know I really appreciate your answer. It fixed my problem! And I emailed the head of the API support my issue and he told me it was limited functionality of the API key I was using. But your suggestion allowed it to work even if I didn't get values back from the API- it just inserted blank cells to the table.